# Is there a way to download data in CSV without using client side?

Tags: javascript, backend

I'm currently working on a script that collects specific data and my end goal is to fetch this data as `csv` file?

I've tried many different methods, but everything leads to having a frontend. I want my script to download only using `cmd` without having any frontend, is that even possible?

Comment: You've tagged JavaScript and seem to be wanting to run JS on a server without a UI. Have you taken a look at [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/)?

Comment: @phuzi I'm running a JS file that has a specific script that fetches data on `npm start` command in shell, I would like to including `csv download` in that script as well

Comment: Can you explain "I've tried many different methods, but everything leads to having a frontend"?

Comment: @phuzi most of the answers I've found require a frontend method that includes fetching data via `window` command, that I assume can not be achieved without frontend

Comment: Yeah, `window` is browser specific.

Comment: @phuzi so is there a way to download without browser?

Comment: @phuzi I believe it is. But that means it's not possible without running `nodejs`?

Comment: curl for windows maybe?

Comment: Yeah, as JavaScript is an interpreted language it is normally run within a host environment like the browser. Node is such an environment that makes it possible to run JavaScript outside of the browser on a server without a UI/Frontend

Comment: @phuzi but my JS runs perfectly without Node environment so far, my only issue is downloading the file. But I believe you're right and I would just need to insert my script into NodeJS server sided file.

Comment: How are you running it currently?

Comment: @phuzi simply `npm start` and specific `js` runs the functions that I require it to fetch data from API. Now I have data, that is being displayed in my `cmd`. My next step to download this data instead of showing it in `cmd`

Comment: npm as in Node Package Manager, sounds like you're already running under Node :o)

Comment: @phuzi cheers Im stupid :D

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*without having any frontend*" - it sounds like you have a backend, which is a webserver serving files, no? If you don't want to use a web (http) server, you can also use an ftp server or a smb or a ssh server.

Comment: Why is this tagged [javascript]?